# Python tkinter removing label after 2 seconds

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, label, destroy

I'm trying to have a Label appear for 2 seconds when condition is met.
User is supposed to enter 3 fields, if they do not, i dont want them to be allowed to proceed. I'm not able to delete this Label called "warnlabel" no matter which approach. Please let me know what am I doing wrong.

```
def get_API_KEYS():  #Main function
    root = Tk()
    """...other declarations / conditions  / window settings ..."""
    def Save_KC_Keys(): #Button press triggers this function
        if len(UE1_var.get()) == 0 or len(UE2_var.get()) == 0 or len(UE3_var.get()) == 0:
            warnlabel = Label(root, text="MUST ENTER ALL 3").grid(row=1, column=3)

            #root.forget(Label)
            #root.after(1000, root.destroy(warnlabel))
            #root.forget(warnlabel)
        """...other conditions..."""
    root.mainloop()
```

I have tried .forget / .destroy / .after (i would prefer .after to work), however in almost every configuration i receive an error such as :

```
return getattr(self.tk, attr)
AttributeError: '_tkinter.tkapp' object has no attribute '_name'

root.after(1000, root.destroy(warnlabel))
TypeError: Tk.destroy() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

self.tk.call('wm', 'forget', window)
_tkinter.TclError: wrong # args: should be "wm option window ?arg ...?"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Attempt to do

```
root.after(2000, lambda: warnlabel.destroy())
```

Try using it without lambda.

And also change

```
warnlabel = Label(root, text="MUST ENTER ALL 3").grid(row=1, column=3)
```

To this

```
warnlabel = Label(root, text="MUST ENTER ALL 3")
warnlabel.grid(row=1, column=3)
```

Comment: You don’t need `lambda` here. You can use it, but it is unnecessary.

Comment: With Lambda:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BEAST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
 return self.func(*args)  File"C:\Users......\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 839, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\BEAST\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\GUI_Test.py", line 77, in <lambda>
    root.after(2000, lambda: warnlabel.destroy())                                       #Remove warning lablel.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: Without lambda:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\BEAST\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\BEAST\PycharmProjects\WebScraping\GUI_Test.py", line 77, in Save_KC_Keys
    root.after(2000, warnlabel.destroy())                                           #Remove warning lablel.
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'destroy'

Comment: Ohh right, it's because you're instantly doing .grid() method. You're storing a nonetype variable.

Comment: warnlabel = Label(root, text="MUST ENTER ALL 3")

Comment: And only then do warnlabel.grid()

Comment: AWESOME!! That worked! (ah man i spent like 3 hours with this -_- , should have come here first!) Thank You!

Comment: No worries bud, getting stuck for hours and hours on a problem is part of being a programmer unfortunately. We all hate it, but it's inevitable